# yii2 Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "550"

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer, contact-form, mailer

i'm using the framwork yii2  and i have a problem in the contact page when i try to send an email i got this error "yii2 Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "550" " even though the configuration of the mailer is correct

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
       'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
       'host' => 'my host',
       'username' => ' my email ', 
       'password' => 'my password',
       'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
     ],
]
```

-the website is live not in the localhost
-the mailer works fine when i send an email from my email to another but not the opposite

please help me

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the problem is that the mail server returned an error code `550` in response to a request from the `swiftmailer` library to "send a mail".
Therefore, you should look at the logs of your mail server.

If access to the mail server log is difficult, then pay attention to the connection settings that you specify in the config.
Often, this 550 error occurs due to incorrectly specified `encryption` / `port` settings or incorrect configuration `smtp`-system of your mail server (if you use your own custom configured mail-server).

For testing, try connecting with the same settings via a desktop mail client (like Thunderbird, Outlook, etc) and send testing mail.

Comment: thank you for your answer  ,  the configuration is correct because i can send an email using   swiftmailer   from  my email to another   but  in the contact page  it suppose to send  an email   "to" my email "from" the  email of any user  . i hope you understand me

Comment: @fathi-dk
Please read my new answer - it may helps you.
My text did not fit into the comment format (too long for comment)

Answer (score 0):

For contact forms, the better way to send mail from your own email to your own email (it may even be the same email).
And in addition to this add "return address" - the `Reply-To` header (exactly the email that the user entered into the contact form).

As a result, you will have a set of headers like this:

```
From: your@domain.com
To: your@domain.com
Reply-To: client@gmail.com
```

The security policy of most mail systems prohibits sending letters on behalf of third-party email.
Even if you succeed, then with a very high probability such a mail will be rejected by the receiving party - because the sender's email does not match the sending server (simply put).
Most likely for these reasons, you have this error.

If you are interested, you may enable logging in swiftmailer - perhaps you will see interesting details in the logs:
https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.1/yii-swiftmailer-logger